# C# & Visual Studio. Anything like this on Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Been reading about C#/Visual Studio and beginning programming. Some of the features, like built in library of methods (.Net) and comment template creation for user created methods (///) seems fantastic. I know of Xcode and Eclipe but is there anything available on Mac like this for creating a variety of apps, i.e. web and windowed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) and [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

Mono is a open source implementation of C# and CLR. You can see [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) how complete is implementation, and quote from that link is:
 "The easiest way to describe what Mono currently supports is: Everything in .NET 4.0 except WPF, EntityFramework and WF, limited WCF."

Answer (score 4):

There is [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/) which is an IDE for Win/Linux/Mac that primarily lets developers create desktop (C#, VB.NET, C/C++, Vala) or ASP.NET applications.

I personally, however, haven't had much luck getting some of my C# desktop applications to run on linux (Mono 2.10.6) because certain namespaces/classes aren't fully implemented (the ones that come to mind are some System.Net classes related to NetworkInterfaces, and understandably, deployment is not ported to linux).